# Parse name and numbers from a string. Put numbers in a vector

Tags: c++, parsing, vector

Given is the format below:

Paul 34 56 72 89 92

I want to read the name and put/parse the numbers into an int vector marks. 
Everything in the format above is separated by a white space.

This is my attempt to solve this. There's a typo ... Rank is actually marks

```
StudentEntry:: StudentEntry(string line) {
    int temp = line.find(' '); // end of the name
    name = line.substr(0, temp); 
    string numbers = line.substr(temp+1);
    for (int i=0; i<rank.size(); i++) {
        rank.push_back(i);
        cout << "RANK: " << rank[i] <<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which is an easy first attempt. You will have to do more research if you want more performance/flexibility.
As you mentioned, this solution requires that the components in the input string are separated by white spaces to be able to produce correct results.
It uses `std::istringstream` which works just like `std::cin`. You provide it the input string and keep reading white-space-separated components from it.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


std::istringstream iss{ line };        // initialize with the input string

std::string name;
iss >> name;                           // extract the first component as a string

std::vector<int> marks;
for (int num = 0; iss >> num;)         // extract rest of the components as int
    marks.push_back(num);              // and store them in a vector
```

Remember that the name cannot contain a white space.
For instance this solution won't work with this input: `Paul Walker 34 56 72 89 92`.
To be able to parse the string with a name containing white-spaces, you will have to delve deeper and do more complex things.